# ¿Query para listar productos de WooCommerce por categoria?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estoy diseñando mi primera plantilla de Wordpress desde 0 y me he topado con este problema. Quiero mostrar todos los productos que hay en una categoria en concreto, pero no quiero especificar la categoria, quiero que la detecte a través de la url. ¿Es posible?

Tengo este código que funciona pero solo me saca los productos de la categoria 41:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => '12',
    'tax_query'             => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
            'terms'         => 41,
            'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_visibility',
            'field'         => 'slug',
            'terms'         => 'exclude-from-catalog', // Possibly 'exclude-from-search' too
            'operator'      => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($products);
```

Lo que necesito es que segun la url a través del menú, por ejemplo ( https://web.com/categoria-producto/salon/mesa-de-salon/ ) me haga una query de los productos que estén en la categoría mesa-de-salon.

¿Alguien puede orientarme?

Answer (score 0):

para hacer uso de las categorías mediante la URL debes trabajar con el archivo category.php, esto quiere decir que si creas este archivo y lo personalizas wordpress le dará importancia a este archivo y no al que usa por defecto.

Bien el siguiente paso es hacer uso de la variable global de wordpress $cat 
con esta puedes consultar tu categoría desde la URL y aportarla como dato de la siguiente forma:

`

```
<?php      
    $catURL = $cat;
    $args = array(
    "post_type" => "YOU CUSTOM POST TYPE",
    "cat" => $catURL
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>



<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`

Saludos